# Calculate conceptual and relation similarity of two words in Java

Tags: java, similarity, lsa, latent-semantic-indexing

I am implementing a readability formula in Java based on [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8029587/) paper.

I reached the point where I have to compute the conceptual and the relational similarity of two or more words.

They say:

> We use Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA) tools to compute word
>   similarity. LSA can derive semantic information, including similarity,
>   from a word-document co-occurrence matrix. Word/term co-occurrences
>   are counted in a moving window of a fixed size that scans the entire
>   corpus. The co-occurrence models using windowsizes of +-1 and +-4
>   considered as relational similarity and conceptual semantic models,
>   respectively.

I tried to see some implementations of LSA, like [this one](https://github.com/rsarathy/LatentSemanticAnalysis), but couldn't find a straightforward way to get what I want.

I supposedly need to have a matrix based on the words, so I tried to use WS4J library to compute the matrix based on two arrays of Strings.

WS4J also has a method `calcRelatednessOfWords()` but the results it gets don't match with the ones shown in the paper.

Is there any library that offers what I want? Or can anyone point me in the right direction?